# Image.frombytes not writing squares

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have a numpy array:

```
[[12 13 12  5  6  5 14  4  6 11 11 10  8 11  8 11  7  8  0  0  0]
 [ 5 14  4  6 11 11 10  8 11  8 11  8 11  8 11  7  8  0  0  0  0]
 [ 5 14  4  6 11 10 10  8 11  8 11  8 11  8 11  8 11  7  8  0  0]
 [ 5 14  4  6 11 11 10  7  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 5 14  4  6 11 11 10  8 11  8 11  8 11  8 11  8 11  8 11  7  8]
 [ 5 14  4  6 11 10  8 11 10  8 11 10  8 11 10  7  8  0  0  0  0]
 [ 5 14  4  6 11 10 10  8 11  8 11  7  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 5 14  4  6 11 11 10  1 11  1 11  7  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 5 14  4  6 11 10 10  1 11  1 11  1 11  7  8  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 5 14  4  6 11 10 10  8 11  8 11  8 11  7  8  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 5 14  4  6 11 10  8 11 10  8 11 10  8 11 10  8 11  7  7  0  0]]
```

And a colors dictionary:

```
{0: (0, 0, 0), 1: (17, 17, 17), 2: (34, 34, 34), 3: (51, 51, 51), 4: (68, 68, 68), 5: (85, 85, 85), 6: (102, 102, 102), 7: (119, 119, 119), 8: (136, 136, 136), 9: (153, 153, 153), 10: (170, 170, 170), 11: (187, 187, 187), 12: (204, 204, 204), 13: (221, 221, 221), 14: (238, 238, 238)}
```

And I'm trying to write pass the array through the dictionary, then write those colors in 10x10 blocks to a .png file. So far I have:

```
rows = []
for row in arr:
    for j in range(10):
        for col in row:
            for i in range(10):
                rows.extend(colors[col])

rows = bytes(rows)
img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (110, 120), rows)
img.save("generated.png")
```

But this writes it like this:

[image]

Which has lines instead of the 10x10 blocks I was trying to write. It seems to me as though the blocks are shifted somehow, but I can't figure out how to un-shift them. Why is this behavior happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you only need to change the size parameter to obtain the result you want. Replacing this line should correct the error:

```
# img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (110, 120), rows)
img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (210, 110), rows)
```

Size should be a 2-Tuple of the width and height of the image in pixels. The *rows* list you are creating is an image that is (210,110) pixels. You are drawing that to an image that is (110,120) pixels. This causes the image to break to a new row every 110 pixels.

Here is a working example:

```
from PIL import Image

array = [
    [12, 13, 12, 5, 6, 5, 14, 4, 6, 11, 11, 10, 8, 11, 8, 11, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0],
    [5, 14, 4, 6, 11, 11, 10, 8, 11, 8, 11, 8, 11, 8, 11, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [5, 14, 4, 6, 11, 10, 10, 8, 11, 8, 11, 8, 11, 8, 11, 8, 11, 7, 8, 0, 0],
    [5, 14, 4, 6, 11, 11, 10, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [5, 14, 4, 6, 11, 11, 10, 8, 11, 8, 11, 8, 11, 8, 11, 8, 11, 8, 11, 7, 8],
    [5, 14, 4, 6, 11, 10, 8, 11, 10, 8, 11, 10, 8, 11, 10, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [5, 14, 4, 6, 11, 10, 10, 8, 11, 8, 11, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [5, 14, 4, 6, 11, 11, 10, 1, 11, 1, 11, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [5, 14, 4, 6, 11, 10, 10, 1, 11, 1, 11, 1, 11, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [5, 14, 4, 6, 11, 10, 10, 8, 11, 8, 11, 8, 11, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [5, 14, 4, 6, 11, 10, 8, 11, 10, 8, 11, 10, 8, 11, 10, 8, 11, 7, 7, 0, 0],
]
colors = {
    0: (0, 0, 0),
    1: (17, 17, 17),
    2: (34, 34, 34),
    3: (51, 51, 51),
    4: (68, 68, 68),
    5: (85, 85, 85),
    6: (102, 102, 102),
    7: (119, 119, 119),
    8: (136, 136, 136),
    9: (153, 153, 153),
    10: (170, 170, 170),
    11: (187, 187, 187),
    12: (204, 204, 204),
    13: (221, 221, 221),
    14: (238, 238, 238)
}
rows = []
for row in array:
    for _ in range(10):
        for col in row:
            for _ in range(10):
                rows.extend(colors[col])
rows = bytes(rows)
img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (210, 110), rows)
img.save("generated.png")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I would have never seen this.